# How did Arkangel still work after Sara became a teenager?

Tags: black-mirror

After watching the new Black Mirror, I've been wondering: if Arkangel was banned in Europe, and was soon to be banned in the US while Sara was still a child, how did it continue to work when she became a teenager?

Surely the company would have been shut down by then, thus making the device useless as the servers would have been turned off?

Or is there something more sinister about the Arkangel system and how it works?

Comment: I don't think they ever actually said that it got banned in the US. The psychologist said something like "it is probably going to be banned in the US soon too" but I don't think they ever actually said it had been banned.

Comment: @stannius that's a good point. It was never confirmed, so we don't know if it ever was shut down.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no real indication that it requires a backend.
Maybe we're supposed to believe it only needs the implant & 'iPad' to function.

This is a similar theme throughout Black Mirror. Technologies are simply a "given" with little explanation as to how they function. Historically, much good sci-fi has done the same. You don't need to know how it works, or even its history, to appreciate the tale being told using that tech as a backdrop. You just have to accept "it works".

Many of the Black Mirror stories are actually 'moral tales' - they just use a tech backdrop to provoke a stronger sense of it not being quite current-day, even though the audience is aware it is indeed a 'mirror' of current society... hence the title.

Comment: I agree, but with that being said, the ambiguity around the tech, especially in an episode where it's about controlling/monitoring children, including it's name, I think does invoke an additional sense of cynicism & something insidious happening behind the scenes. -It wouldn't be much of a stretch to imagine this was military-tech testing, even though we don't actually know it to be true.

Comment: "Historically, much good sci-fi has done the same", totally agree. Even if I personally would enjoy some more science explanation and integrity, sci-fi cinema that dives too deep into the science unfortunately tends to make most audiences feel alienated.

Comment: Not the explanation of the title given here https://www.google.co.uk/amp/www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/black-mirror-called-black-mirror-11831977.amp#ampshare=http://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/black-mirror-called-black-mirror-11831977

Comment: ermm... aside from it being (Daily) Mirror, not an actual newspaper, it doesn't disagree with what I wrote. It simply fails to get that far and stops at the obvious, then adds a bunch of dodgy fake tweets to make it sound like a complete and utter revelation.

Comment: @DarthLocke: Men Against Fire actually heavily relies on Arkangel-like technology: alterations to perception, tracking soldiers' vitals, functioning as a bodycam, ...

Comment: It's not that far-fetched to think that in a world where Arkangel technology is possible (for consumers), that internet access is a public resource, e.g. full WiFi coverage in all built up areas. If so, then it's perfectly possible for Sara's implant and the tablet to find each other. Servers are only really necessary if they either (a) provide an "always available" service when devices aren't always expected to be online at the same time as each other or (b) are used as a way of securing/authenticating data; which is only really relevant when customers _exchange_ information.